# Columns in poster, Tikzposter

Tags: posters

I would like to have my poster divided into several squares, meaning on the left it might be one big square with a picture. to the right of that square i would like the same vertical space to have to squares. is this possible?
I have included all my code to give a perspective.

also i have a picture of what i mean, just to clarify
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW56i.jpg

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}


%Fjerner vandmærke i bunden
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

%billede placering
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Omfartsvej ved Gørding}
\author{Gruppe BA3-1-2020}
\date{\today}
\institute{Aalborg Universitet, Esbjerg}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}

\usetheme{Board}


\begin{document}
\node [below left=1.5cm and 2cm] at (topright) {\includegraphics[width=14cm]{AAU stortbilled.png}};

\maketitle

\block{Gørding}
{
     Gørding er en stationsby i Sydvestjylland tæt på E20 Esbjergmotorvejen og med omkring 1500 indbyggere. Gørding er en af de byer der har oplevet en større mængde gennemkørende trafik, herunder af tunge køretøjer, de seneste år. Dette har medvirket til en øget usikkerhed for de bløde trafikanter omkring Gørding Skole, og byens hovedgade. Der er derfor et stort ønske fra borgerne, at den gennemkørende trafik til og fra motorvejen, samt den tunge trafik, ledes udenom byen. 
}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Introduktion}
    {Projektgruppen har undersøgt hvilke udfordringer der var i forbindelse med anlægning af en omfartsvej omkring Gørding by. Dette har mundet ud i en todelt rapport, hvor første del er planlægningsdelen, og anden del er projekteringsdelen. Disse rapporter gennemgår regler og love udstukket af Vejdirektoratet, samt relevant beregning og teori for anlægning af en omfartsvej. 

            \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Gordingby.png}
        \end{tikzfigure}


    }
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Problemformulering}{På baggrund af projektoplægget ”Infrastrukturelle anlæg” og opgaveanalysen udledes følgende problemformulering: \\
    "Hvorledes kan en omfartsvej, anlagt uden om Gørding, planlægges og udformes således, at denmedvirker til at reducere den gennemkørende trafik, øge trafiksikkerheden og mindske øvrige gener for trafikanterne og borgerne i Gørding?"}
    
     
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Blok}{Block til skrivning}
\end{columns}



\begin{columns}
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Besigtelse af Gørding}{ Under besigtelse af Gørding by blev det klart at der var et problem med både landbrugskøretøjer og lastbiler på hovedstrækningen igennem Gørding. \\
    Yderligere blev det fundet at teræænet vest for Gørding, ville kræve stor forarbejdning før anlæggelse af en omfartsvej, grundet store terrænforskelle
            \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{lastbilogtraktor.jpg}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Metoder}{Der er gjort brug af AutoCad og Novapoint til tegning af omfartsvejen. Yderligere er der blevet samlet research online og i bøger, blandt andet er der blevet gjort brug af Vejdirektoratets håndbøger for tracering i åbent land. Til opstart af projektet blev der lavet en interessepartsanalyse. Yderligere har der været vejledning af Jens, leif leif leif lars lars lars}
    
        \column{0.33}
    \block{tom blok}{ekstra blok}
    
    
\end{columns}




\begin{columns}
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Resultater}{Skriv hvad vi er kommet frem til som løsning, evt nyt billede af omfartsvej}
    
      \column{0.33}
    \block{Et billede af Omfartsvejen}
    {
        \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{AAU stortbilled.png}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
    
      \column{0.33}
    \block{Diskussion}{Oprindeligt blev der udarbejdet tre linjeføringsforslag, hvoraf den vest om Gørding blev kaseret grundet x. Herefter blev der udarbejdet en Cost/Benefit analyse for de to resterende linjeføringsforslag. Disse bestod af to muligheder øst om, en kort og en lang. På baggrund af Cost/Benefit analysen blev det valgt at arbejde videre med den linjeføring der er blevet døbt "Øst om, kort". Under projektering af denne linjeføring blev det nødvendigt at ændre i det oprindelige udkast for at opnå lige strækninger med mulighed for overhaling, samt at ramme både Holsted Å og Jernbanen i Gørding så vinkelret som muligt, da det her skal opføres broer.
    }
\end{columns}



\block{Konklusion}{Formålet med omfartsvejen er at aflaste Gørding for den trafik, der kører til og fra motorvejen. Dette skaber utryghed hos borgerne, da trafikken blandt andet består af tung trafik og landbrugskøretøjer. 
Under udarbejdelse af løsningen er der gjort brug af Vejdirektoratets håndbøger for veje i åbent land, og det vurderes at omfartsvejen lever op til disse samt projektoplæggets formulering. Ved hjælp af disse sikres det endvidere, at vejen har en god æstetisk i forhold til omgivelserne, mens der samtidig er sikret en behagelig og sikker køreoplevelse qua samspillet mellem vertikale og horisontale kørekurver.
Alt i alt kan det konkluderes, at der er fundet en fordelagtig og rentabel løsning. Etableringen af den projekterede omfartsvej vil forbedre fremkommeligheden, trafiksikkerheden samt trygheden for de lette trafikanter i Gørding.
}

\block{Referencer}{Hvad har vi referet ofte til, hvor har vi hentet hjælp og inspiration\\
Vejdirektoratets håndbøger, bl.a Tracering i åbent land\\
Udformning af kryds i åbent land\\
Afvandingskonstruktioner\\}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

use column to start a column, and block after that to define blocks inside that column.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}


%Fjerner vandmærke i bunden
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

%billede placering
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Omfartsvej ved Gørding}
\author{Gruppe BA3-1-2020}
\date{\today}
\institute{Aalborg Universitet, Esbjerg}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment}

\usetheme{Board}


\begin{document}
\node [below left=1.5cm and 2cm] at (topright) {\includegraphics[width=14cm]{AAU stortbilled.png}};

\maketitle

\block{Gørding}
{
     Gørding er en stationsby i Sydvestjylland tæt på E20 Esbjergmotorvejen og med omkring 1500 indbyggere. Gørding er en af de byer der har oplevet en større mængde gennemkørende trafik, herunder af tunge køretøjer, de seneste år. Dette har medvirket til en øget usikkerhed for de bløde trafikanter omkring Gørding Skole, og byens hovedgade. Der er derfor et stort ønske fra borgerne, at den gennemkørende trafik til og fra motorvejen, samt den tunge trafik, ledes udenom byen. 
}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Introduktion}
    {Projektgruppen har undersøgt hvilke udfordringer der var i forbindelse med anlægning af en omfartsvej omkring Gørding by. Dette har mundet ud i en todelt rapport, hvor første del er planlægningsdelen, og anden del er projekteringsdelen. Disse rapporter gennemgår regler og love udstukket af Vejdirektoratet, samt relevant beregning og teori for anlægning af en omfartsvej. 

            \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{Gordingby.png}
        \end{tikzfigure}


    }
    \column{0.33}
    \block{Problemformulering}{På baggrund af projektoplægget ”Infrastrukturelle anlæg” og opgaveanalysen udledes følgende problemformulering: \\
    "Hvorledes kan en omfartsvej, anlagt uden om Gørding, planlægges og udformes således, at denmedvirker til at reducere den gennemkørende trafik, øge trafiksikkerheden og mindske øvrige gener for trafikanterne og borgerne i Gørding?"}
    
     
    \block{test}{masser af skriverier}
    
       \column{0.33}
    \block{Besigtelse af Gørding}{ Under besigtelse af Gørding by blev det klart at der var et problem med både landbrugskøretøjer og lastbiler på hovedstrækningen igennem Gørding. \\
    Yderligere blev det fundet at teræænet vest for Gørding, ville kræve stor forarbejdning før anlæggelse af en omfartsvej, grundet store terrænforskelle
            \begin{tikzfigure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{lastbilogtraktor.jpg}
        \end{tikzfigure}
    }
\end{columns}




\end{document}
```